# How do you invoke program in bash and give a variable

Tags: bash, scripting

While trying something similar in a bash script I made this snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash
your_animal="fishies"
zenity --info --text="Do you like to eat $your_animal?"
if zenity --entry --title="Root Partition" \
--text="what is your favorite animal"
    then your_animal=$?
    else exit
fi
#echo $your_animal
zenity --info --text="Do you like to eat $your_animal?"
exit
```

which prints

> Do you like to eat fishies?
>
> Do you like to eat 0?

also maybe we could make this into wiki for the same problem in other languages, like perl.

Comment: Are you sure? I get `fishies` all right.

Comment: It works fine for me too.  You're not showing us the code that cause the problem.  Copy-and-paste the *exact* content of your script.

Comment: @KeithThompson I updated the code; I think it may be a problem with zenity.

Comment: I managed to get it to work can we plz delete this topic; sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$?` is the status of the last executed command.  In your case, it's going to be 0, so the displayed text `"Do you like to eat 0?"` is correct.

To get the output of a command, use

```
`command`
```

or

```
$(command)
```

Try this:

```
result=$(zenity --entry --title="Root Partition" \
        --text="what is your favorite animal")
if [ $? = 0 ] ; then
    your_animal="$result"
else
    exit
fi
```